# How do I access the elements from this queryset in a template?

Tags: django, templates, distinct, django-queryset

Here is the queryset:

```
researches = Graph.objects.filter(subject=subject_object).exclude(type='infografik').values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

When I do:

```
{% for research in researches %}
```

in my template, the code in between executes the right amount of times, but for example `{{ research.name }}` doesn't work.

How to I access the object's attributes?

Thanks.

edited:

Graph model

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
research = models.ForeignKey('Research')
explanation = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
path_to_file = models.CharField(max_length=100)
type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=type, null=True, blank=True)
subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/', null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120, unique=True)
```

Comment: Your using value_list - this will not give you an object where you can access properties like this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: I was reading the documentation but I had a hard time understanding it. What can I use to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> Each tuple contains the value from the respective field passed into the values_list()

So to print research names just do :

```
{% for research in researches %}
{{ research  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asking for a flat list of values, there are no attributes to access. If you want access to all of the attributes, use either this query `researches = Graph.objects.filter(subject=subject_object).exclude(type='infografik').distinct()` which will return a queryset that can be iterated over or this one `researches = Graph.objects.filter(subject=subject_object).exclude(type='infografik').values().distinct()` which will return a list of dicts. In django's template language, you can access attributes in both like so:

```
{% for research in researches %}
    {{ research.name }}
    {{ research.author }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

---

The only way I know of to also get distinct objects is to use raw sql:

```
researches = Graph.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM appname_graph WHERE subject_id = %s AND type <> %s GROUP BY name', [subject_object.id, 'infografik'])
```

Comment: What I need is to get a list like I do with duplicate values removed (to not show two Graph objects with the same name). This I get with this query, but I need to be able to access all of the attributes. Do you have an idea how can I do this?

Comment: ok, but this lists all of my objects, I have tried this already. the thing is that the objects are distinct in every way except the 'name' attribute, and I need to make them distinct by name. The problem that I can't use `distinct('name')` because I don't use PostgreSql.

Comment: @Tamara Can you post your Graph model then?